# How to Change color of topmost visible cell in StickyCollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to change colour of the top most visible cell in collection view which is being overlapped by another cell in the application https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stickyflowlayout.
Can anyone please help me to solve this.